# Mutiple HighchartsV5 components not rendering when Locker Service is active (error 16)

Tags: lightning-aura-components, salesforce1-app, locker-service, winter17, highcharts

Multiple Highcharts component is not rendering when Locker Service is activated. 
The [individual Highcharts rendering issue](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/146577/29317) was solved after the Patch 12.1 update from the Salesforce in the Winter '17.

But the old [Highcharts error 16 issue](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/128041/29317) still persists when we try to load multiple Highcharts components.

I've created created an [**unmanaged package**](https://login.salesforce.com/packaging/installPackage.apexp?p0=04t28000000L4Fe) for replicating the issue when Locker Service is Active.

**Details of the unmanaged package:-**

There are three main Lightning components viz. **Test**, **firstChart** and **secondChart**.

`firstChart` and `secondchart` component comprises of Highcharts. I've put both of these components inside the main component, ie., in this case, `Test`.

When Locker Service is active only one of them is rendered. Whereas when Locker Service is deactivated, both of them are being rendered whose screenshots are as below.

**When Locker Service is Active:-**

[image: Only one chart is being rendered when LS is active]

**When Locker Service is Deactivated:-**

[image: Both the charts are being rendered when LS is deactivated]

PS: My use case is using the independent chart components in multiple places inside the app. I've created such a package only to replicate the same issue.

Comment: That is progress. Unfortunately I only now noticed on the original post that a moderator decided to delete my answer because it should have been a comment: "How are you loading the Highcharts js files? Are you using ltng:require?" Do you have a case open on this? Unlike the secure virtual DOM issues that have now been corrected this one should be easy enough to address. There was a bug in ltng:require under Locker that was not insuring once and only once loading semantics but that also has been fixed.

Comment: ... I am installing the package above to take a closer look - we will get this resolved ASAP.

Comment: Excellent repro case @SE_User - providing that unmanaged package is always such a help! I can see that all scripts are loaded using ltng:require (very good) - digging into this more now. Do you have a case on this yet?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is a bug in ltng:require that has been fixed in Spring'17 already but has not yet been back ported to Winter'17 patch. I am looking into getting this fast tracked into the next Winter'17 patch that deploys to production Tuesday. This is being tracked by **W-3461135**.

Comment: Thank you so much @DougChasman for confirming the issue and for the reference number to track the same. Ok, waiting for the patch to be deployed to production. Once again, thanks a lot for looking into this.

Comment: You are very welcome - and thank you for your patience! I can confirm that I committed the back port of the fix for ltng:require to Spring'17 .14 patch last night and it is scheduled to deploy to production Tues/Wed depending on instance.

Comment: Hi @DougChasman
Eventhough error #16 has been resolved, there's still error when you click on the graph. 
`[NoErrorObjectAvailable] TypeError: properties can only be defined on Objects.`

Comment: Hi @DougChasman Highcharts Error #16 is present in Microsoft Edge browser in windows Desktop.